# Generating a data structure

Tags: python

I have a code that looks like this:

```
f= open("new_sample.txt","r")
for ranges_in_file in f:
    if(ranges_in_file.find('ranges:')!= -1):
    new_data = ranges_in_file
    print('succes')
    new_data = new_data.strip('ranges:')
    new_data = new_data[2:-2]
    values = new_data.split(',')

    values = float(values)


    print (values)
```

the contents of the values are something like: `['2.8369998931884766', ' 2.8459999561309814', ' 0.4269999861717224', ' 0.3659999966621399', ' 0.3059999942779541', ' 0.289000004529953', ' 0.2919999957084656', ' 0.2919999957084656', ' 0.2919999957084656', ' 0.2809999883174896', ' 0.28700000047683716', ' 0.2939999997615814', ' 0.3499999940395355', ' 0.3700000047683716', ' 3.128999948501587', ' 3.1419999599456787', ' 3.1689999103546143', ' 3.2079999446868896', ' 3.239000082015991', ' 3.2799999713897705', ' 3.319999933242798', ' 3.3499999046325684', ' 1.6139999628067017', ' 1.5789999961853027', ' 1.5490000247955322', ' 1.5169999599456787', ' 1.4730000495910645', ' 1.4559999704360962', ' 1.4229999780654907', ' 1.3919999599456787', ' 1.3680000305175781', ' 1.340999960899353', ' 1.3270000219345093', ' 1.297999978065490`

I will need to generate a data structure out of it, it should be a scatter plot? However, i have an error like 
`TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number.` How do you guys suggest i fix this problem

Comment: You are trying to convert the list of strings to a float - won't work. Instead, iterate over the list, converting each element to a float and store it in a second list.

Comment: Do you intend to separate the float values in a list?

Comment: map the list to `float`: `values = list(map(float, values))` https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#map

Comment: Dirtybit, i am trying to generate a data structure, something like a graph using matplob or some sort

Comment: I am not too sure if seperating the float values in a list will help in me achieving my results

Answer (score 0):

If you want a list of the floats you can do

```
values = list(map(float, a))
```

and if you prefer a numpy array to use matplot lib you can do

```
n_vals = np.array(list(map(float, a)))
```